Is it possible to make tooltip with suggestion wider?
I'm writing a C# application in the VS Code with plugins C# Dev Kit, C#. When I try to get all overloads of a method I get the tooltip with the list of parameters. The size of this tooltip is very small, as I think.
How it looks like now:

As we can see, the editor has enough space for a wider tooltip, but it doesn't use it.
I've tried to extend the width of the tooltip using Developer Tool, and it looks like this:

I think it looks much better than the previous screenshot. But this method is not persistent. Is it possible to extend this width without workarounds?
